# "Взы(и)маемый": через И или через Ы?

Tags: орфография

Если по аналогии с "безысходные", "взыскание", то слово "взымаемый" должно писать через Ы, но в тексте я видела написание через И.
Почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аналогия тут наименее весомый из возможных доводов.
Есть общее правило, что после приставки на согласный корневое И последовательно заменяется на Ы. 
Но "взимать" - это слово-исключение (кажется, единственное). Связано с тем, что в этом слове утратилось представление об историческом корне "(н)имать". Сравните исторически родстственные "отнимать", "снимать" и проч. Замечу, что по этой модели должно бы быть "взнимать", но в данном случае "протеза" Н не проявляется из-за скопления согласных. Это тоже можно рассматривать как косвенный довод в пользу написания через И.

Поэтому: ***взимать, взимаемый*** и т.д.

Comment: А как вы объясните слово "изымать"? А также следующие соответствия: взять - взимать, изъять - изымать. А также то, что российские пользователи на знают, как писать: взымать или взимать, то есть в принципе перестали писать по слуху. Возможно, на них влияют слова-исключения, которые непонятно из чего исключенные и с какими  историческими моделями связанные?

Answer (score 1):

Если к слову, которое без приставки начиналось с буквы И, прибавили приставку на согласную, то И меняется на Ы: интересный - безынтересный. А слова ИМАТЬ в  таком виде нет.Значит оно уже с приставкой, поэтому замены не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить на данный конкретный вопрос, желательно представить его общую теорию в виде следующего рассуждения.

Чередование Ы/И после мягких и твёрдых согласных – обычное явление для суффиксов и окончаний, обусловленное правилами русского письма, например: разбрасывать – заготавливать, голыш – мякиш  – чередование Ы/И в суффиксах ЫВА/ИВА, ЫШ/ИШ; столы – земли – чередование Ы/И в окончании.

Большинство приставок в русском языке заканчиваются на твёрдый согласный, поэтому в корне на И также происходит чередование звуков И/Ы, которое  может отражаться или не отражаться на письме.

Основной формой является отражение чередования Ы/И : искать – отыскать, играть – обыграть, розыгрыш, история – предыстория, идея – безыдейный и др.

Замена И на Ы не делается в нескольких случаях как исключение (дезинформация, межиздательский, мединститут, сверхинтересный, двухимпульсный). Это сложносокращенные слова, слова с иноязычными приставками, а также приставки на Ж и Х.

Что касается слова "взимать", то буква И пишется ПО СЛУХУ (приставка на мягкий согласный здесь является редким исключением).

Таким образом, буква И в корне слова может писаться, если в виде исключения чередование И/Ы не отражается на письме(контригра) или если мы слышим звук И и обозначаем его буквой И по слуху (взимать).

Comment: Но "предисловие" не имеет приставки на согласный?

Comment: Да, я слово убрала из ответа, здесь редкий вариант приставки ПРЕД(И)

Comment: Не понял, вы что произносите "взимать" с мягкой "з" ?